# What is the hand gesture called when you knock down your opponent in a fight?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

Is there a word or an idiom for the hand gesture, done after finishing a task successfully or after knocking down the opponent in a fight? The one like wiping off the dust from your hands, which indicates it's a victory but it was easy for you. Not done to gloat, just happens spontaneously as if it's a natural gesture.

Comment: The idiom *dust off* comes to mind.

Comment: It's totally gloating. No one does that spontaneously

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I call it *dusting your hands together*

Comment: Phrased a number of different ways, such as "dusting off", "dusting hands", "dusting off hands", etc. Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ujlxYcd3Wg, and you can find it in Wikipedia's [list of gestures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gestures) as "Hand-dusting".

Answer (score 2):

**brush your hands**

> According to local lore, when God was satisfied with Creation, and **brushed his hands** together, the crumbs that fell unnoticed from his fingers into the sea formed Cape Verde.
>   <sub>[Google Books: Cape Verde Islands By Aisling Irwin, Colum Wilson](https://books.google.com/books?id=eJKxRVu1390C&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

He ***brushed off*** his opponent.

The act of wiping something from your shoulder more readily portrays this.